MS Access update query based on second form selection
All,
I have a couple of tables that I’m using to track parts orders and am trying to use their forms together.  I have 2 tables:
Orders
Lines
I also have a query named LinesByOrderTaskId
So each order has a unique TaskId that I am using as the primary key and the foreign key for the Lines table.  The query takes a parameter called SelectedOrder and pulls the lines for that order.
So I have created a form for the Orders table and a Form for the LinesByOrderTaskId queries.
I have created a third form that has the orders form on the left and the query form on the right.  I’d like to set it up so that when I select a different order line, the query form is updated.
I’ve been googling for days and can’t seem to find a solution.  I currently have the following subroutine that seems to do absolutely nothing to the table on the form.  It is called anytime a different line on the order table on the combined form is selected.  I’ve verified the correct taskid is being received, but it doesn’t do anything.
Public Sub UpdateLinesByOrder(strValue As String)
 
    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Dim db As Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("OrderLinesByTaskId")
   
    'close query if opn.
    If (SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acQuery, "OrderLinesByTaskId")) Then
        DoCmd.Close acQuery, "OrderLinesByTaskId", acSaveNo
    End If
   
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("OrderLinesByTaskId")
   
    qdf.SQL = "SELECT * " & _
              "FROM OrderStatus INNER JOIN OrderLines ON OrderStatus.StausId = OrderLines.StatusId " & _
              "WHERE (((OrderLines.TaskId)=[" & strValue & "]))"
   
    qdf.Close
   
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("OrderLinesByTaskId")
End Sub

It is a bit of a conglomerate of what I have been finding online, but it is apparently worthless…
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You said "The query takes a parameter called SelectedOrder and pulls the lines for that order", but there is no SelectedOrder in your query's SQL.  So please help us understand that parameter: where and how is it used; how does it get a value at runtime?

Why not use form/subform arrangement? Otherwise, review https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp#:~:text=We%20synchronize%20the%20subforms%20using%20the%20Link%20Child,Link%20Master%20Fields%20properties%20of%20the%20detail%20subform.
